# Windows Scheduler execute page on the internet

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

Can anyone tell me how I can use windows scheduler on windows server to execute a page over the internet, specifically an asp.net file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single line Powershell script to do this.  Put this in a file with a .ps1 extension (such as RunWebPage.ps1):

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://www.mysite.com")
```

Then in your run box enter

```
powershell c:\RunWebPage.ps1
```

using the full path of wherever you save the script.

Comment: That's a much more elegant solution than mine, I'll have to give it a try here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the run box

```
"c:\program files\internet explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "http://webaddress"
```

but it will only work if someone is logged on.

Comment: Can't you use task scheduler to run the task as a specific user?

Comment: thought this would be a common thing to do? :-/

Comment: I've done it just like coljil suggested -- with the task configured to run as a named user. Nobody needs to be logged on for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @Chris_K, that's what I figured. Good to have it confirmed!

Comment: ... that being said, I *think* you'll want to ensure that named user _has_ logged onto the box at least once before (seems like I had an issue once where no local profile stuff existed yet).

Comment: You could create a local account for this, giving it the least amount of rights needed. Another option is to create the task using the AT command (though this runs the task as the system account, so be careful).

Answer (score 0):

You can user wget for windows, it is simple and works well.
Download it from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).